# "Read_Ncol" exit with error code -1073740791

Tags: python, igraph

I am using python 3.5.3 and igraph 0.7.1.

Why the following code finishes with `"Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)"` error message.

```
from igraph import Graph

g = Graph.Read_Ncol('test.csv', directed=False)
```

test.csv

```
119 205
119 625
124 133
124 764
124 813
55 86
55 205
55 598
133 764
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Read_Ncol](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Read_Ncol) function reads files in NCOL format, as produced by the [Large Graph Layout](http://lgl.sourceforge.net/) program.

Your example works fine for me, also on Python 3.5.3 with igraph 0.7.1.

```
>>> g = Graph.Read_Ncol('test.csv', directed=False)
>>> g
<igraph.Graph object at 0x10c4844f8>
>>> print(g)
IGRAPH UN-- 10 9 --
+ attr: name (v)
+ edges (vertex names):
119--205, 119--625, 124--133, 124--764, 124--813, 55--86, 205--55, 55--598,
133--764
```

It seems the error C0000409 means "Stack Buffer Overrun" on Windows, which probably means that your program is writing outside of the space allocated on the stack (it's different from a stack overflow, [according to this Microsoft Technet Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2009/01/28/stack-overflow-stack-exhaustion-not-the-same-as-stack-buffer-overflow/).)